# Troubleshoot a Full Transaction Log (SQL Server Error 9002)

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

we have quite a bit of automataion which runs at scheduled times, however I do not manage this and the person who does is on annual leave. Of course it's all fallen over

Usually the go to fix is to update the tbl_Control which contains columns to advise whether any of the automation is already running and delete the running field. One job started but has failed and I'm unable to clear the running field on the tbl_Control and that is where all the automation falls over providing variations of the message below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Using:

```
SELECT        log_reuse_wait_desc, name, database_id, state, state_desc
FROM          sys.databases
```

It states the database (for which the transaction log is full)

> log_reuse_wait_desc ACTIVE_TRANSACTION

So I think I need to stop that running and start again but as I can't update the tbl_Control I'm stuck.

Now I think I might have to do something in SQL to the database (maybe to clear the Transaction Logs, or make space?) but I have no idea

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to backup transaction log. You can also extend the size of the transaction log if it has fixed size. The last thing you can do is to check the disk space on the partition where your transaction log is stored and free some space. But backup transaction log should be first.

Backup Transaction log:

1. Connect with SSMS to your server.
2. Select your database under Server Name->Databases->[Your database name] and right click on it.
3. Choose 'Tasks'->'Back Up...'
4. On page 'General' select 'Transaction Log' as 'Backup type'
5. On page 'General' select 'Disk' as 'Back up to'
6. On page 'General' add new destination clicking 'Add..' button
7. Click [OK].
8. Notify administrator about backup you did.

Comment: Thank Jacek, so how to do I approach this. I use SQL to run queries and that's about it so anything like this sort of Database Administration I'm unfamiliar with

Comment: Try to follow steps I added to my response.

Comment: Thanks for the simple step by step instructions, however I only have the options: FULL or DIFFERENTIAL for Backup type. Does this mean I don't have the correct permissions? I'm able to see the option for Transaction Log on other Databases which show in the log_reuse_wait_desc as LOG_BACKUP

Comment: Monkeydave this means that your database is not in FULL recovery mode. So you are not able to backup your transaction log. In this case, try to check disk space on the drive where your log file is stored. Execute this query select file_id,type_desc,size,max_size,physical_name from sys.database_files; If the max_size for LOG is different then -1 then it means that the file cannot grow. In PHSYSICAL_NAME column you get location of your log file maybe the disk is full.

Comment: I don't know about your backup and restore procedures, but it seems your database is on simple model. Check the properties of your database. Change to register "Options" and change Recovery model to Full. After that make a full backup of your database. Then you should be good. Otherwise make a backup of the transaction log, as described by @JacekWróbel. Afterwards switch the database back to simple and make a new Full Backup. Archive the last backup (or whatever you do with the database backups). You should be good to go again